# Integrating Android App into WordPress

Tags: android, iphone, wordpress

I'm looking for a way (if it's possible) to integrate an iPhone and Android App
into a WordPress site somehow. Even if I used an iframe to do so.

I honestly have no clue where to start as everything I search for is resulting in WordPress>App and not App>WordPress.

Comment: are you saying that you have an iPhone/Android app and you want to somehow run it in an iframe within a wordpress site? Showing the wordpress site in an app is easy (use a WebView) but putting an app that requires a device runtime onto the web is going to be very tough outside of something like the Amazon "TestDrive" capability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it it impossible until PHP interprets Java or Objective-C codes.